# How do I convert all my print outputs into a single string

Tags: python

This code prints out a hollow rectangle with a given width and height using stars(*), but instead of printing each segment at a time I need to modify it or create a code that will create a single string that when printed produces the same output as the code above.

```py
def print_rectangle(width, height):
    for p in range(1):
        print("*" * width)
        for i in range(height - 2):
            for i in range((width + 1) - width):
                print("*", end='')
            for n in range(width - 2):
                print(" ", end='')
            for j in range((width + 1) - width):
                print("*", end='')

            print("")
    print("*" * width)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable, that saves the substrings, than print out the whole string, like this:

```
def print_rectangle(width, height):
tmp_str = ""
for p in range(1):
    tmp_str = "*"*width+'\n'
    for i in range(height-2):
        for i in range((width+1)-width):
            tmp_str += "*"
        for n in range(width-2):
            tmp_str += " "
        for j in range((width+1)-width):
            tmp_str += "*"
        tmp_str += '\n'

tmp_str += "*"*width+'\n'

print(tmp_str)

print_rectangle(4, 5) #or any other numbers
```

Comment: (1) You have a typo (`tmpp_str`) (2) You don't return the string (3) The `print` doesn't actually call the function, and `tmp_str` is not global so it will give an error (perhaps you meant to indent it?) (4) You don't add newlines (`"\n"`) to the string so it won't give the right result anyway.

Comment: (1) Your code doesn't work due to incorrect indentation. (2) `tmp_str = ""` is superfluous. (3) The `for p in range(1):` loop is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

The question has already been answered of how to correct your own code to make the rectangle, so here is a totally different way to accomplish the same thing:

```
def rectangle(width: int, height: int) -> str:
    top_bottom = "*" * width
    middle = "\n*" + (" " * (width - 2)) + "*"
    
    rect = top_bottom
    for _ in range(height - 2):
        rect += middle
    
    if height > 1:
        rect += "\n" + top_bottom

    return rect

print(rectangle(10, 5))
```

Output:

```
**********
*        *
*        *
*        *
**********
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build the lines into a list then join them for a single print operation. Here's an example:

```
width = 5
height = 6
t = ['*' * width + '\n']
m = '*' + ' ' * (width-2) + '*\n'
t.extend(m * (height - 2))
print(''.join(t+[t[0]]), end='')
```

**Output:**

```
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```